# Extract the month number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table like this one, and I want to extract the month as a number (1 to 12)

[image]

I tried to do something like

```
For i = 2 To 1165

StartMonth2 = Range("G" & i).Value
StartMonth = Month(StartMonth2)

Next i
```

but this doesn't work because the month is not part of a date, is just on a column on its own.

I also tried the TEXT formula, something like =TEXT(G2, 'm') but again, the same issue.

Is there a function in VBA that can help me extract the month number easily?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function

Comment: Do you need VBA? This is easily doable with worksheet formulas.

Comment: @BigBen I could also do it with a formula, how can I do that?

Comment: @BigBen this gives me #VALUE! as a formula, and Type mistmach on VBA. Earlier I tried to use the "concat" formula to create the data and it worked in a way, but then when I tried to use the date created on a separate code that checks the date as Cdbl(StartTime) then it wouldn't recognize it as a date.

Comment: Try `=MONTH(1&G2)`.

Comment: Try =LOOKUP(G2;{"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May" ...."Oct";"Nov";"Dec"})   Month names as in your column ``Month``

Comment: @BigBen That worked, if you post it as an answer I will select it as the answer to my question.

Comment: Your question is already closed as a duplicate.